# Parallax background images not scaling for iPad

Tags: image, ipad, background-image, scale, parallax

Trying to get the background images in my [website](http://adicristoforo.com) to scale 100% width on the iPad/tablets...

I've implemented the below which seems to have worked for others, but not for me!

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

CSS:

```
img { max-width: 100%; }


/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
}
```

I have a feeling it might have something to do with the below which appears in the parallax script i'm using, but if I remove it then it breaks the parallax effect and the images just swipe and don't scale even on desktop.

```
    $bgobj.css({ 
 backgroundPosition: coords,
 '-webkit-background-size': 'cover',
 '-moz-background-size': 'cover',
 '-o-background-size': 'cover',
 'background-size': 'cover'
```

Anybody have any ideas that could help ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and kept running across this question, so maybe my answer might help someone else.

`background-attachment:scroll;`

in the `css` for the div that has the problem with its background image not scaling.